# .NET Web API "plugin" assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-assembly, appdomain

> Doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results.
>   *— Insanity; also my current frame of mind*

---

I have a feeling I'm just missing some key detail, or I'm doing something stupid (*see **tl;dr***)

I have an ASP.NET Web API 2 project in which I'm trying to support "plugin" assemblies. The plugin assemblies can/will contain any combination of additional Web API controllers and other types (*data providers, business strategy algorithms, etc.*)

- `MyProject.Common` (*interfaces, contracts, etc., is referenced by all*)
- `MyProject.Core.Api` (*only references `Common`; loads `Components` assemblies*)
- `MyProject.Components.One` (*also only references `Common`*)
- `MyProject.Components.Two` (*also only references `Common`*)

I'm trying to isolate the plugin assemblies to a `plugins` directory. Right now (*to test*) on build I'm copying the output (*`*.dll`*) of the component projects to `MyProject.Core.Api\plugins`

I'm trying to load the plugin assemblies in the magical `Application_Start()` method:

```cs
var directoryName = this.Server.MapPath("~/plugins");
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
var assemblySet = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.dll")
    .Select(fileInfo => Assembly.LoadFrom(fileInfo.FullName))
    .ToList();
```

Now, I do all this before I call [`HttpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479134(v=vs.118).aspx), and considering that the default [`IAssembliesResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dispatcher.iassembliesresolver(v=vs.118).aspx) service is  [`DefaultAssembliesResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dispatcher.defaultassembliesresolver(v=vs.118).aspx), and considering that all `DefaultAssembliesResolver` does is:

```cs
return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
```

In any case, **it didn't work and the controllers could not be found.**

---

From here, I started following [Customizing controller discovery in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/) and have implemented a custom `IAssembliesResolver`; rather, I derived from `DefaultAssembliesResolver` as per the blog post.

This only started working though, when I also added:

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
      <probing privatePath="bin;plugins" />
```

However, **I can't see other types** (*data providers, etc.*). I iterated over types that implement a common-layer interface (*I created a `MyTestThingy` in one of the component projects*) and tried to instantiate it via [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) and got `null`<sup>§</sup> instead

<sub>§: Perhaps this has something to do with assemblies being loaded multiple times?</sub>

---

I think I'm doing something wrong, or right at the wrong time.

My goal is, ultimately, to just load all the damned assemblies in the `~/plugins` folder into the running `AppDomain`, so that the Web API controllers can be resolved, and so I can use component implementations of other things.

I'm aware you can't "unload assemblies", and instead need to unload the `AppDomain`, so I'm hoping that, if I need to refresh the loaded assemblies, I can use [`HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) to force a reload/refresh on the next request.

- Am I loading the plugin assemblies at the right time? If I'm not, when should I?
- Am I using the correct loading method? I know there's [`Assembly.LoadFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Assembly.LoadFrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`Assembly.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx), and furthermore that they use different loading contexts (*as per example, I'm using `LoadFrom()`*)
- Since the `AppDomain` shares the lifetime of the IIS Application Pool, are there other considerations I should make? And can I force a recycle/reload?
- What the hell am I doing wrong?

> **tl;dr** — Is there no simple way to manage runtime-loaded "plugin" assemblies in ASP.NET, specifically with Web API, such that you can pull `ApiController` types, and anything/everything else into the host application? And, moreover, force the application to reload the `AppDomain` and thus all of the plugin assemblies?

---

- I've tried tinkering with [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/index) and frankly it's pretty lame. I get what it tries to accomplish, but it imposes some silly constraints (*you have to kludge the API just to get a list of exported types, rather than instances*) that were purposefully baked in.
- [MAF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/add-ins/) is nightmarish, and feels like trying to kill a fly with a cannon. Also, I don't want to have to bounce between each `AppDomain` with [`MarshalByRefObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Take a look at NopCommerce repo on Github and see how they implemented Plugins https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/tree/develop/src/Libraries/Nop.Core/Plugins

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, I'll have a look through it. Are you familiar with that codebase? If so, does the `BuildManager` factor into their approach? I'm learning quite a bit, seeing how they manage shadow copies and such, but if you can elaborate on any of their design choices, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: I only discovered this repo late last week and I am still in the process of reviewing it. I have not had time to fully inspect the plugins module but did remember that it was there when I read your question. Thought it would have been a good resource for you to check out.

Comment: Awesome, well thank you! I'll keep perusing it. If you happen to conclude anything before I do, please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @Nkosi I can't figure out what they're doing :-( There's a lot going on there.